# pass runat="sever" or control of asp.net value to html tags

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

my runat="sever" tag

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
```

my html tag

```
<form >  
<input type="text" name="requestparameter" id="requestparameter" ><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit">
</form>
```

when i used to click submit button i want Label1.Text value stored in requestparameter

Comment: You can use jquery for this before form submit.`$("#requestparameter").val($("#Label1").text);`

Comment: @Nilesh I have tried but its not working <script>
        function SetValue() {   $("#requestparameter").val($("#Label1").text);
}
    </script>....   <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="SetValue()">

Comment: That might not be working cause you have Label1 as runat server. Check what Id is generated by the server for the label. Or you can use `ClientIdMode = static` as suggested by @skhurams

Comment: @Nilesh i have tried using skurams code but it is passing value of requestparameter to Label1 and thats only for a second ...but i want Label1 value to requestparameter

Comment: You are using asp.net yet you have a `<form>` tag and outside of that you have a control with `runat="server"`? If you then have a form wrapping all of this `<form runat="server">` then you are going to run into more problems. IE will not render the HTML correctly.

Comment: add `return false` to the onclick function called. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help

```
        <form > 
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode='static' runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:Label> 
            <input type="text" name="requestparameter" ClientIDMode='static' id="requestparameter" onclick='SetValue' ><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit">
            </form>
            <script>
            function SetValue(){
    document.getElementById('<%=requestparameter.ClientID %>').value=     document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: where you call SetValue() function ?  Why you add ClientIDMode='static' to requestparameter ?

Comment: I want label1 text value to requestparameter....not the requestparameter value to label1

Comment: tried using  <script> document.getElementById('requestparameter').innerHTML = document.getElementById('Label3').value </script> but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You would like to put a debugger in the script and check what value you get from the label.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#testid").click(function () {
                debugger;
                $("#requestParameter").val($('#<%=label1.ClientID %>').text());
                alert($("#requestParameter").val());
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server"  ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="Hello"></asp:Label>
    <input type="text" id="requestParameter" />
    <input type="button" value="test"  id="testid"/>
</asp:Content>
```

**EDIT: Modified the code. This works as expected.**

Comment: What is the ID generate by the server for `Label1`?

Comment: I really dont have an IDE in front of me, but I have edited the code which you can try. Basically its like old ASP code. Can you try that?

Comment: ofcourse it support <input type="text" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" /> i have checked

Comment: @skhurams i was telling about <input type="text" name="requestparameter" ClientIDMode='static' id="requestparameter" >  in this ClientIDMode='static' is not supporting

Comment: use small case clientidmode and use ranat=server also

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try what Nilesh has wrote

Or you can try this.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
<form >  
       <input type="text" name="requestparameter" id="requestparameter" ><br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="SetValue()">
</form>
<script>
    function SetValue()
    {
        $("#requestparameter").val($("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text());
    }
</script>
```

because when asp.net renders HTML it will convert ID of element differently then that it was in aspx page.
if you want to get the value of ID when it will rendered  you can use Control.ClientID property.

Comment: are you trying to get value on the server

Comment: are you getting any error in browser console. to see error you can press F12

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to post anything to server, follow the answers posted before but with `return false`

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="hello"></asp:Label>
<form >  
       <input type="text" name="requestparameter" id="requestparameter" ><br />
       <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="SetValue()">
</form>
<script>
    function SetValue()
    {
        $("#requestparameter").val($("#<%= Label1.ClientID %>").text());
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

`return false` will prevent the Default function of the event. ie: post form to server is the default functionality of a submit button.

Instead of adding `return false` you can change `<input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="SetValue()">` to `<input type="button" name="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="SetValue()">` (see the change in type)

Also, remember to add the jQuery refernces.